# Duplex with Javascript? (and flash?)

Tags: javascript

Is there a solution to duplex data with javascript? I dont mind if flash is used. All i need to send and receive text.

The solution must work with FireFox 3.6+.

Answer (score 2):

One common technique here is to maintain two connections.  You send by posting an XHR, and if your target is firefox, your best bet for receiving data is a mime-multipart-replace page continuously loaded from the server side.

You may find it a lot easier to use one of the many comet servers that are already out there, that provide simple APIs for pub/sub style full duplex communication.